# How many mappings are there from 0 to 1? from 0 to 0? from 1 to 0 and how many elements does 0 have?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, solution-verification

This is my answer for the first three questions:
Since 1 is the terminal object there exists exactly one mapping from 0 to 1.
There is 1 mapping from 0 to 0 because o is the initial object in the category.
There is one mapping from 1 to 0 since 1 is the terminal set and then then there's another mappin from 1 to 0 because 0 is the initial object. Therefore, in total there are 2 mappings from 1 to 0.

I am struggling with the fourth part.Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you working in the category of sets and $0 = \emptyset$ and $1 = \{0\}$, or are you working in an arbitrary category (with an initial and a terminal object)? In the latter case, it makes no sense to ask for the number of elements of $0$. Also, $1$ being terminal does not mean there is a map from $1$ to $0$ and neither does $0$ being initial mean that.

Comment: The property of being a terminal object only talks about maps *to* $1$; it tells you absolutely nothing about what kinds of maps come *from* $1$. Similarly $0$'s property only tells you about maps *from* $0$. So how can either of those tell you about anything $1\to 0$?

Comment: this is exercise 1.18 from sets for mathematics by William Lawvere. I am working In an arbitrary category with an initial and terminal object. Could you explain a bit more as to why 1 being terminal doesn't ensure there is a map from 1 to 0 because from my understanding 0 is an object in the category so, there exists a unique arrow from 0n to 1.

Comment: You say this is an exercise from a book about *sets*, but your post fails to mention any particular sets.  Instead your post refers to $0$ and $1$, which are numbers.  Perhaps there is some important context missing from the Question, if indeed those numbers are to be understood as *represented by sets* in a way to make problem sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about $0\to 1$ and $0\to 0$, but not about $1\to 0$. The property of being a terminal object only talks about maps *to* $1$; it tells you absolutely nothing about what kinds of maps come from $1$. Similarly $0$'s property only tells you about maps *from* $0$. So neither of these properties can tell you anything about maps $1\to 0$.

It should be noted that Lawvere is *not* talking about an arbitrary category here, but the category of abstract sets, for which he has given some axioms. The most recent such axiom is that $0\not\simeq 1$, and this is what will answer your question.

Notice that if there is a map $x:1\to 0$ then the composite $1\overset{x}{\to}0\to 1$ is the identity on $1$, and $0\to 1\overset{x}{\to}0$ is the identity on $0$, meaning exactly that $0\simeq 1$. So there can be no such $x$. Since for Lawvere an element of $X$ *is* just a map $1\to X$, this also answers how many elements of $0$ there are.

Comment: So, 0 has no elements since there are no maps from 1 to 0.

Comment: @Elise - Exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm new to category theory so apologies about the lack of knowledge in the area. I am struggling to understand the meanings of the arbitrary category and category of abstracts sets. could you please explain.

Comment: So, Lawvere is axiomatizing a very special kind of category in this book, one that behaves like the category of sets and functions that you get from a first order set theory like ZFC. But categories in general needn't have an initial object like $0$, or a terminal object like $1$, or they may have both and have $0\simeq 1$, etc. It's important to understand that Lawvere isn't describing categories in general in this book; he's describing one very specific category.

Comment: I understand now. Again, thank you very much.